# do two insert queries in a table python

Tags: python, mysql

I have a table H0001 with *Date, Time, Open, High, Low, Close, Volume, Bull, Bear*. (total 9 columns).
Since I need to capture data from two different sources (text files), I separately insert the data set, dataset1: (*Date, Time, Open, High, Low, Close, Volume*), dataset2: (*Date, Time, Bull, Bear*).
I inserted data by using python with this statement:

```
cur.execute("""REPLACE INTO H0001 (Date, Time, Open, High, Low, Close, Volume) VALUES ('%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s')""" % (KDate, KTime, KOpen, KHigh, KLow, KClose, KVolume))
```

error occurred as 
    "Data truncated for column 'Bear' at row xxxxx"
The data can be insert in respective columns.

Eventually I ran the following code:

```
cur.execute("""REPLACE INTO H0001 (Date, Bull, Bear) VALUES ('%s','%s','%s')""" % (KDate, KBull, KBear))
```

error occurred

```
cur.execute("""REPLACE INTO  H0001 (Date, Bull, Bear) VALUES ('%s','%s','%s')""" % (KDate, KBull1, KBear1))
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 205, in execute
self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 36, in defaulterrorhandler
raise errorclass, errorvalue
OperationalError: (2013, 'Lost connection to MySQL server during query')
```

But when I create a new table, I can insert the data well for just Date, Time, Bull, Bear.
What's wrong with the database?

Comment: Increase the `connect_timeout`or reconnect to [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/error-lost-connection.html), the code between the two queries is probably taking to long and thus the connection with MySQL is closed.

Comment: The connection was separated. i connected the database by two different python files. Run the first one for date,time, OHLCV and then the second one for bull bear.

Comment: Any idea on how many rows are being updated? You should [read this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/error-lost-connection.html) for more information.

Comment: The file only contains one row. The error pop up immmediately when i ran the second code. I think it was due to the error occurred in the first code. In addition, the second code has no error if i run it in other database which only contains 4 columns DATE, TIME, BULL, BEAR...

Comment: I have tried to setup another table with 9 columns to repeat the same procedure, same error pop up...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

REPLACE itself will destory the data entered, so i could not use the second code to update the data. I should use UPDATE instead if there is data already existed in that entry.